# How are command line argument are treated in toplevel?

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-toplevel

I have a program which takes command line argument. The same of source file is encode.ml. I want to load this file in the toplevel.

Is there way to load the source file in the toplevel where we can pass it a command line arguments?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, invoke your toplevel with `ocaml encode.ml arg1 arg2 etc`. The following program demonstrates it:

```
$ cat args.ml
let () =
  Array.iteri (Printf.printf "%d -> %s\n") Sys.argv

$ ocaml args.ml -h --help -help
0 -> args.ml
1 -> -h
2 -> --help
3 -> -help
```

Comment: Invoking toplevel this way, exits  it immediately. What I wanted is to stay in the toplevel so that I can see the input argument. My program has 20 odd argument, I would like to inspect those values and alter it and see which one of it causing unexpected behavior.  I wonder if there is way to tell #use directive of toplevel to take argument.

Comment: sorry, but no. But you can mock it, by first invoking it with 20 dummy arguments, and then by editing them directly with `Sys.argv.(n) <- "-x"`. But with this you can't change the amount of arguments.

Comment: What is happening is when I invoke a toplevel as "$ ledit -l 100 ocaml -I _build/ encode.ml arg1 arg2 arg3...", I fell back to shell prompt '$' and not toplevel prompt '#'.  So I am not getting chance to modify the input argument as you suggested.